# Is it possible to have conditional EF migration code?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have two environments - development and production.
Stored procedures in my application are bit different for each environment, internally they use different linked servers and other subqueries that are server specific, but procs have the same input parameters and output result columns.

I put all procs into migrations, but when it came to deployment I found that I need some sort of conditional migration code to deploy production specific stored procedures.

Is there any way to run different migration code based on config settings or project target like Debug, Release etc? 
Have somebody faced with something simmilar when you have to have different environment specific migration code?

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

You could use an #if directive in your migration like this:

```
#if Release
    Sql("Update...");
#elif Debug
    Sql("Delete...");
#endif
```

When you build your solution you just have to pass which configuration you are building (Debug, Test, Release etc).

Answer (score 0):

I bit late to this party but I ran in to this when migrating to EF.Core and wanted to only update some things in development.
Environment variables work quite well for this
e.g.

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development")
...
```